# parity - Computer wiped clean. How to bring parity back with my coins?

Tags: parity, recovery

I've got some RLC coins in my parity wallet/node but computer was wiped clean. How to bring it back. I've saved the 16 different number & letter combinations.

Comment: Just restore your account from your backups! You have backups, do you?

Answer (score -1):

If you still have the seed phrases, use the recovery feature: https://blog.parity.io/restoring-blank-seed-phrase/

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Also, this blog article is not explaining how to use recovery phrases at all.